# build failed due to babelrc, presets[0] [1] must be an object, false or undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm having issues with babel. I'm trying to use async/await in my application, and for that I needed to add the node option in babelrc.
However, I'm getting this error:

I checked this question, but I'm a fair rookie and I don't really see where my problem lies.
[Plugins[0][1] must be an object, false, or undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775030/plugins01-must-be-an-object-false-or-undefined)

My babelrc file:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15):

I found my fix:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "node": "10"
        }
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Comment: If you followed this tutorial (https://medium.com/@danlegion/react-server-side-rendering-with-express-b6faf56ce22) it says vaguely where it should go but, I thank you for helping me I was stuck here too Thanks

Comment: The heck; anyone know why the order matters here?

Comment: never mind; it's how you wrap the parameters in the sub array
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/presets#preset-options