# .plugins[0][1] must be an object, false, or undefined

Tags: ios, react-native, npm, babeljs, babel-loader

I faced mentioned error when I ran my project in `iOS`. As per this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775030/plugins01-must-be-an-object-false-or-undefined) issue must be in `babel.config.js`,

My `babel.config.js` looks likes this,

```
 module.exports = {
 presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
 plugins: [[
     "react-native-reanimated/plugin",  
     "babel-plugin-transform-remove-imports", {
        "test": ['react-toastify', 
            'exceljs', 
            'file-saver', 
            /excelutils/, 
            'react-select', 
            'react-popover', 
            'react-router-dom', 
            'react-pivottable', 
            'react-chartjs-2', 
            'react-data-grid', 
            'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes', 
            'chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels', 
            'file-saver',
            'create-react-class',
            'react-dropzone', 
            /documentuploadmodal/, 
            /richtextmodal/, 
            /locationmastermapmodal/]
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

This is my `package.json`

```
   "devDependencies": {
      "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
      "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
      "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
      "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
      "eslint": "7.14.0",
      "jest": "^26.6.3",
      "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
      "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
   }
```

I couldn't find any flaw in `babel.config.js`.

Note: I am facing this issue only when running in `iOS`. working well in `Android`.
Running in `Xcode 13.2.1`

Can some one help me to resolve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have included two plugins in a nested array. Also, *reanimated* was recommended to be placed at the end. Change that to the followings:

```
[
    [ 'babel-plugin-transform-remove-imports',
        {
            test: [ 'react-toastify',
                'exceljs',
                'file-saver',
                /excelutils/,
                'react-select',
                'react-popover',
                'react-router-dom',
                'react-pivottable',
                'react-chartjs-2',
                'react-data-grid',
                'chartjs-plugin-colorschemes',
                'chartjs-plugin-piechart-outlabels',
                'file-saver',
                'create-react-class',
                'react-dropzone',
                /documentuploadmodal/,
                /richtextmodal/,
                /locationmastermapmodal/ ],
        },
    ],
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
];
```